# billing.save(); not firing as guest

Tags: onepage-checkout, billing, save

I'm using the rwd theme that came with Magento 1.9. I just modified the styling a bit. The problem is now, if I want to buy a product the checkout is working fine. But if I want to order something as a Guest I can't get past the Billing fields step. The button does nothing, not even a javascript error in the console.

Other things I've tried:

- Disabled all third party modules
- Disabled the other jquery scripts that does give an error in console
- Cleared cache and everything, private browser etc.

Anybody came across this bug and had an solution? If anybody wants to give it a go, check: 
http://yentlmobile.staging.pixelindustries.com/

Comment: Not sure if this has something to do with it but you are missing the email address field in the billing address.

Comment: That is actually a very good point, but where the hell did it go..

Comment: if you are expecting me to tell you where it went, you have to wait a long time. I didn't take it :)

Comment: yes! that was it, thanks a bunch, don;t know how I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email field is made display:none in your OPC. That is the reason you can't go past billing address. Please check the screenshot

[image]

This may be either you have applied **display:none** in CSS or maybe some third party module Jquery is conflicting due to which **display:none** is being applied.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Came from a third party module. Thanks to the both of you